# Token renew each time a new Jhipster application is deployed

Tags: jwt, jhipster, access-token, keycloak

I have a Jhipster running inside of a docker in a server, and the other side as an authentication server I have a docker running. Each time that a user wants to connect, Jhipster does the authentication with Keycloak, generating a user access token. Basically is the solution proposed to Jhipster on their web page.

**Problem:**
The problem is that every time I change the Jhipster application, I compile and build a new docker image, that replaces the old one, and everyone that has an active access token needs to create a new access token.

Does someone know how can change this behavior or create a token that keeps active even after the new deployment?

Comment: Are you sure it's due to app deployment. Or could it be due to Keycloak container using an embedded H2 database by default? https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#oauth2

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yes, I'm sure, every time I deploy a new app, the access token doesn't work anymore. Nothing more is deployed. Keycloak and Jhipster app work on servers differents, keycloak is configured with Postgres DB and with a volume set to its container.